# Appending every nth column using loop in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which consists of paired columns of ratings given by participants and the reasons for giving their ratings. I would like to insert a blank column after each pair of columns, so that after column 1 and 2 there's a new column. I managed to do this manually by creating a vector, inserting them all at the end, and then reorganizing myself. Here's the code for that so it is clear what I am trying to achieve:

```
v <- rep(NA, 184)

Scheme1$Code1.1 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.1 <- v
Scheme1$Code1.2 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.2 <- v
Scheme1$Code1.3 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.3 <- v
Scheme1$Code1.4 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.4 <- v
Scheme1$Code1.5 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.5 <- v
Scheme1$Code1.6 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.6<- v
Scheme1$Code1.7 <- v
Scheme1$Code2.7 <- v

# Reorganize
Scheme1 <- Scheme1[,c(1,2,15,16,3,4,17,18,5,6,19,20,7,8,21,22,9,10,23,24
                      ,11,12,25,26,13,14,27,28)]
```

I wanted to see how this could be achieved by using a for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: In the example above, I inserted two columns. This would be the most desired outcome, but I was wondering how I would go by adding one to start with.

Comment: can you provide `dput(Scheme1)`? There's probably a pretty straightforward answer but it's hard to tell without knowing what the names of the existing columns look like. You could do it just using column indexes, but the resulting code would give no clues about the logical reasoning behind the action being performed. It probably makes more sense to view this as acting on specific columns or groups of columns with specific names.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, may be this helps

```
lst1 <-  split.default(Scheme1, as.integer(gl(ncol(Scheme1), 2, ncol(Scheme1))))
do.call(cbind, unname(Map(function(x, i) {x[paste0(names(x), ".", i)] <- NA;x}, lst1, names(lst1))))
```

#### dta

```
set.seed(24)
Scheme1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(14 * 5), ncol = 14))
```